# Break while loop in GPIO.RPi callback event

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, gpio

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, to no avail.
So, I've been trying to run an OLED screen for showing the weather, time, etc. I wrote the script with a while loop so it can run virtually forever. However, I also want to be able to start the script with a GPIO pull-up, and end it with yet another high GPIO pin.
Using the on-off script to start the OLED script works flawlessly with variables, yet the script seems to be blind to the variable changes my "Off-GPIO" tries to introduce. Here's my code:

```
from oledscriptwithfunc import oledfunc
from reset import rstfunc
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
var = None
def button_callback(channel):
    print("Initializing..")
    oledfunc(2) # set on-off variable to two so while loop can start (see next block of code)
def offbutton(channel):
    print("Ending program..") 
    oledfunc(1) # set on-off variable as off..
    rstfunc()  # reset OLED screen

GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 
GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback) # GPIO on "switch"
GPIO.add_event_detect(9,GPIO.RISING,callback=offbutton) # GPIO off "switch"
message = input("Press enter to quit\n")

GPIO.cleanup() 

--------------------------oledscriptwithfunc.py-------------
def oledfunc(var): # function used in previous script, var is set by GPIO
    var = var
    import digitalio
    import threading
    import busio
    import board
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

    import requests
    import adafruit_ssd1306
    oled = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, i2c, addr=0x3c)

    oled.fill(0)
    oled.show()
    image = Image.new("1", (128, 32))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, 128, 32), outline=255, fill=255)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    import datetime
    oled.image(image)
    oled.show()
    import time
    timer1 = time.perf_counter()
    while var != 1: # used for on-off toggle
        timer2 = time.perf_counter()
        if int((timer2 - timer1)) in range(0,1) or int((timer2 - timer1)) % 1800 == 0:
            response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=xxxx&lon=xxxxx&lang=de&units=metric&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            data = response.json()
            for weatherdata in data['weather']:
                status = weatherdata['description']
            redvar = data['main']
            temp = redvar['temp']
            temptext = "{}C".format(temp)
        
        else:
            while var != 1: # on-off toggle variable
                t_end = time.time() + 10
                while time.time() < t_end:
                    now = datetime.datetime.now()
                    testvar = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                    vartwo = now.strftime("%M:%S")
                    newvr = int(now.strftime("%H"))
                    newervr = newvr + 2
                    text = testvar + " " + "{}:".format(newervr) + "{}".format(vartwo)
                    draw.rectangle((0, 0, 128, 32), outline=255, fill=255)
                    draw.rectangle((6, 6, 122, 26), outline = 0, fill = 0)
                    (font_width, font_height) = font.getsize(text)
                    draw.text((oled.width//2 - font_width//2, oled.height//2 -  font_height//2),
                            text, font=font, fill=255)
                    oled.image(image)
                    oled.show()
                draw.rectangle((0, 0, 128, 32), outline = 0, fill = 0)
                (font_width, font_height) = font.getsize(temptext)
                draw.text((oled.width//2 - font_width//2, oled.height//2 - font_height//2),
                    temptext, font=font, fill=255)
                oled.image(image)
                oled.show()
                time.sleep(5)
                draw.rectangle((0, 0, 128, 32), outline = 0, fill = 0)
                text = status
                (font_width, font_height) = font.getsize(text)
                draw.text((oled.width//2 - font_width//2, oled.height//2 - font_height//2),
                    text, font=font, fill=255)
                oled.image(image)
                oled.show()
                time.sleep(5)
```

I apologize if there is a lot of bad code in here, I'm just starting out with programming and Python. I hope I've explained the issue well enough. To summarize: With the "var" variable, I want to be able to turn "oledscriptwithfunc.py" on and off. The problem is that I can only start it, but never change the variable again so I can turn it off. I've commented the most important/non-functional bits of the code. Please ignore the OLED setup/weather API calls, I just thought I should include it to show the entire inner-workings of the code. Is there something conflicting, or am I just using the wrong method to make this work?

Comment: What is the point of the second while loop of the var after the else statement? (The condition is already satisfied from the main while loop.

Comment: You are never changing the value of var inside the while loop. Therefore, you are stuck in one state and you are not able to control/change the state (On/Off).

Comment: Oh! that while loop is used to infinitely repeat the OLED print code/time-date update if it's not time to update the weather info. The condition is redundant, you're right. while True would've sufficed.

Comment: Use the driver in the kernel for OLED (`fb_ssd1306` from FBTFT, here pointers to DTS: https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/364). Then just use regular framebuffer library and don't use all these ugly custom RPi libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after some tinkering, I found a solution!
I discovered that RPi.GPIO has a simple way to check a pin's state with input.GPIO(channel). [This teached me a valuable lesson: Always read the documentation] I just did some simple if and while statements to solve my issue. This way has its caveats on its own, but it does what I want it to do.